# How to configure μTorrent for a VPN?

Tags: vpn, bittorrent

I am using a VPN connection successfully for browsing but I have trouble when using it for torrents. I am sure that P2P is enabled by the VPN company so I must be missing some configuration. I know the host IP address and username password, but nothing else.
How should I configure μTorrent to work under a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help:[utorrentVPN](https://www.bolehvpn.net/utorrent.html)

Go through this tutorial and you will probably solve your issue?

Comment: Could you edit the essential parts of the link into your answer, in case the link dies?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have completed the OpenVPN installation first.

Use version 2.2.1 or later, for stability, and to avoid leak-outside-the-proxy issues which would defeat the purpose of a VPN.
Preferences | Connection
Leave Listening Port as Default.
Set on:
 Enable UPnP port mapping
 Enable NAT-PMP port mapping
 Add Windows Firewall exception
 Use proxy for hostname lookups
 Use proxy for peer-to-peer connections
 Disable all local DNS lookups
 Disable features that leak identifying information
 Disable connections unsupported by the proxy
Set off:
 Randomize port each start
 Authentication
Proxy Server Type: Socks5
Proxy: 10.10.10.1
Port: 1080